# Divide and Conquer - Comparing all possible combinations

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

This problem has been bugging me ever since I have been working on it. I am trying to figure out a way to find out if certain people live together based on their pairs. Example, I am given a list:

```
X[] = guy1, guy2, guy3, guy4, guy5
```

I need a D&C algorithm to compare all elements of this list to see if at least half are living together. To find out if they live together, there is a simple function given: `LivesTogether(x, y)` that returns true if they do, false otherwise.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say 'at least half are living together', do you mean `LivesTogether(guy1, guy2) and LivesTogether(guy1, guy3) and LivesTogether(guy2, guy3)` or do you mean `LivesTogether(guy1, guy2) and LivesTogether(guy3, guy4)`?

Comment: The latter. LivesTogether(guy1, guy2) and LivesTogether(guy3, guy4) Theyre unique.

Comment: so guy1 and guy3 can't live together at all? in this case why do you need to divide and conquer? why not just scan each pair as you find them and check?

Comment: because the input is a list of people, not pairs. Need to find all combinations of respectable pairs, check if they live together, and return true if at least half are.

Comment: D&C algorithm mean u need use on a parallel paradigm? Otherwise just follow Viv's suggestion.

Comment: I found a similar question that might be easier to explain: 
"You are given N number of DNA samples. Devise a D&C algorithm that returns true if at least half of the samples correspond to the same animal." where you can determine if two DNA samples are the same animal by a function FUNC_CHECK(dna1, dna2)

Comment: It seems odd that you are trying to figure out a way to solve your problem, but specifically want a divide & conquer algorithm to do it.  Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 0):

```
define a new collection of <guy,guy> tuples

foreach guy1 in the list
   foreach guy2 in the collection of guys positioned after guy1 in the list
       if guy1 != guy2 and LivesTogether(guy1, guy2) 
           then add <guy1, guy2> to collection

if the number of tuples in the collection is greater than 1/4 of the number of guys
    then at least half the guys are the collection (and therefore live together)
```

Comment: You'll get twice as many pairs as you want because you'll be adding pairs based on the results of `LivesTogether(guy1, guy2)` and `LivesTogether(guy2, guy1)` to the collection. Those roommates should only be counted once.

Comment: How is this divide and conquer?

Comment: @vic: It isn't divide and conquer. It also loops more than it needs to and is therefore slower than it needs to be. It runs in O(n^2). We can do better than this.

Comment: I was thinking we make a function called 'majority', so after the D&C breaks it into its roots, its calls the function LivesTogether and finds the majority, but still confused ;(

Comment: If you were comparing identities or hash codes instead of `LivesTogether()`, you would do this just like solving a game of Concentration (add unmatched into a `Set`, use identity/hash/whatever to look up new guys and match if found).  But given `guyX`, there's no way to know without checking all unpaired guys who he matches.  Is there?

Comment: @Asaph - looping more than it needs to be in this case does not make it O(n^2).  Think of Bubble Sort, where the inner loop executes fewer and fewer times as the outer loop progresses - it's still O(n^2) despite that 'optimization'

Comment: @Phil: I get that. But in this pseudo-code I can't see how the inner loop executes fewer and fewer times. He isn't popping any guys off the list as he adds his tuples. If he was doing that, then I think it would loop fewer and fewer times. But he isn't. So I think this is still O(n^2). Do you disagree?

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer.  I somehow missed the divide and conquer requirement, but I don't immediately see how to apply it.

Comment: @Asaph - I agree that he isn't looping fewer and fewer times in his code.  I was talking about Bubble Sort when I said that.  I disagree that looping fewer times changes the Big-O of the algorithm.  I think this is basic Big-O stuff here.  If you halve the inner loop upper bound each iteration of the outer loop, you get O(nlogn) naturally, but if you decrement by a constant - be it 1 or 2 or 17 - you still end up with O(n^2).

Comment: @Phil: Yes. I agree. I didn't mean to imply that looping fewer and fewer times changes the Big-O. My solution loops fewer and fewer times and it's better than this one but still O(n^2) as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's my solution in Java with a unit test to prove it (sorry about the length). This is also not really a divide an conquer algorithm but it is more efficient than the other answer as it doesn't check if guy1 is the roommate of guy2 *and* check if guy2 is the roommate of guy1.

The `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods were generated by Eclipse and needed for my `HashSet` to work correctly.

`Guy.java`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Guy {
    String name;
    List<Guy> roommates;

    public Guy(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.roommates = new ArrayList<Guy>();
    }

    public boolean addRoommate(Guy roommate) {
        return this.roommates.add(roommate) && roommate.roommates.add(this);
    }

    public List<Guy> getRoommates() {
        return this.roommates;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.getName();
    }

    public boolean livesWith(Guy potentialRoommate) {
        return this.roommates.contains(potentialRoommate);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Guy)) {
            return false;
        }
        Guy other = (Guy) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

`Roommates.java`:

```
public class Roommates {
    private Guy guy1;
    private Guy guy2;

    public Roommates(Guy guy1, Guy guy2) {
        this.guy1 = guy1;
        this.guy2 = guy2;
    }

    public Guy getGuy1() {
        return this.guy1;
    }

    public Guy getGuy2() {
        return this.guy2;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return guy1 + " lives with " + guy2;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((guy1 == null) ? 0 : guy1.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((guy2 == null) ? 0 : guy2.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Roommates)) {
            return false;
        }
        Roommates other = (Roommates) obj;
        if (guy1 == null) {
            if (other.guy1 != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!guy1.equals(other.guy1)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (guy2 == null) {
            if (other.guy2 != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!guy2.equals(other.guy2)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

`RoommateFinder.java`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class RoommateFinder {
    List<Roommates> roommates;
    List<Guy> guys;

    public RoommateFinder(List<Guy> guys) {
        this.roommates = new ArrayList<Roommates>();
        this.guys = guys;
        // clone the guys List because findRoommates is going to modify it
        List<Guy> cloneOfGuys = new ArrayList<Guy>();
        for (Guy guy : guys) {
            cloneOfGuys.add(guy);
        }
        this.findRoommates(cloneOfGuys);
    }

    private void findRoommates(List<Guy> guys) {
        Iterator<Guy> iter = guys.iterator(); 
        if (!iter.hasNext()) {
            return;
        }
        Guy firstGuy = iter.next();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Guy potentialRoommate = iter.next();
            if (firstGuy.livesWith(potentialRoommate)) {
                Roommates roommates = new Roommates(firstGuy, potentialRoommate);
                this.roommates.add(roommates);
            }
        }
        guys.remove(firstGuy);
        this.findRoommates(guys);
    }

    public List<Roommates> getRoommates() {
        return this.roommates;
    }

    public List<Guy> getGuys() {
        return this.guys;
    }

    public int getUniqueGuyCount() {
        Set<Guy> uniqueGuys = new HashSet<Guy>();
        for (Roommates roommates : this.roommates) {
            uniqueGuys.add(roommates.getGuy1());
            uniqueGuys.add(roommates.getGuy2());
        }
        return uniqueGuys.size();
    }

    public boolean atLeastHalfLivingTogether() {
        return this.getUniqueGuyCount() * 2 >= this.guys.size(); 
    }
}
```

`RoommateFinderTest.java`:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RoommateFinderTest {
    private List<Guy> guys;
    private Guy harry, larry, terry, barry, herbert;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        harry = new Guy("Harry");
        larry = new Guy("Larry");
        terry = new Guy("Terry");
        barry = new Guy("Barry");
        herbert = new Guy("Herbert");

        harry.addRoommate(larry);
        terry.addRoommate(barry);

        guys = new ArrayList<Guy>();
        guys.add(harry);
        guys.add(larry);
        guys.add(terry);
        guys.add(barry);
        guys.add(herbert);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        harry = null;
        larry = null;
        terry = null;
        barry = null;
        herbert = null;
        guys = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindRoommates() {
        RoommateFinder roommateFinder = new RoommateFinder(guys);
        List<Roommates> roommatesList = roommateFinder.getRoommates();
        Roommates[] expectedRoommates = new Roommates[] {
                new Roommates(harry, larry),
                new Roommates(terry, barry)
                };
        assertArrayEquals(expectedRoommates, roommatesList.toArray());
        assertTrue(roommateFinder.atLeastHalfLivingTogether());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution in java using [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/),by the way it's not a D&C algorithm but i guess you will get the answer using this:

```
Set<Set<Integer>> set=Sets.filter(Sets.powerSet(Sets.newHashSet(1,2,3,4,5)), new Predicate<Set<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Set<Integer> arg0) {
        if(arg0.size()==2)
         return true;
        return false;
    }
});

for(Set<Integer> s:set) {
    System.out.println(s);//use your function here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way how you can achieve O(n) performance - run pairing check on GPU. That is each guy can do it's check on pairings separately from the others - as different thread on GPU. Simply represent each guy as pixel on image, and write pixel shader / compute shader / CUDA task / OpenCL task/ whatever/ which calculates and outputs

- white pixel if it has any pairings in image, or
- black pixel - if it doesn't have pairings.

Then upload resulting image to system memory, and calculate with CPU - how much white pixel you've got. In principle such GPU task would run in linear time (assuming that your video memory is big enough to hold all pixels (aka guys/dna) ).

Answer (score 0):

I think what u can do is generate all possible pairs (n choose 2) using Divide and Conquer, and Then call the function LivesTogether(x,y) for all pairs generated.
I can give u Divide and Conquer algorithm to generate all possible pairs.

```
public ArrayList<String> genPairs(String s[])
   {
        if(s.length<2)
          {
             System.out.println("No Pairs possible");
             return null;
          }

         if(s.length==2)
          {
            ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
            result.add(s[0]+s[1]);
            return result;
          }

          else
          {
              String x=s[s.length-1];
              String s1[]=new String[s.length-1];
              for(int i=0;i<s.length-1;i++)
                 s1[i]=""+s[i];

              ArrayList<String> sub=genPairs(s1);
              ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
              result.addAll(sub);
              for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
                {
                     result.add(s1[i]+x);
                }
                return result;
          }
   }
```

U simply need to pass the String array as input example: "A","B","C","D" and this method will give u an ArrayList of all possible pairs. Now iterate through this list and call LivesTogether on each pair. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Which consists on finding roommates groups by following these steps:

1. Add all people pending to visit
2. Traverse all people finding their respective roommates
3. We don't need to get the roommates of a person if it's not pending to visit anymore since it already belongs to a roommates group.
4. Verify if the number of found roommates are at least 50% of all people and return true if it's the case, otherwise keep searching on the next group.
5. Repeat 2-4 until we get to the end of the list of people
6. return false at the end since any group met the 50% criteria.

Space complexity: O(n).
Time complexity: O(R*n).
where:
**n** is the number of people (input size)
**R** the number of roommates groups

Worst case is when every single person lives alone and thus the number of groups is equal to the input. Running in O(n*n)

```
public boolean halfLiveTogether(String[] people) {
        if(people == null) {
            return false;
        }
        
        Set<String> toVisit = new HashSet<>();
        
        // start with all people to explore
        toVisit.addAll(Arrays.asList(people));
        
        for(String person : people) {
            
            if(toVisit.contains(person)) {
                
                int roommates = getRoommates(person, people, toVisit);
                
                if(roommates >= people.length / 2) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    

private int getRoommates(String roommate, String[] people, Set<String> toVisit) {
            
            int roommates = 0; // assuming liveTogether(x, x) returns true (a person is roommate with themself)
            
            List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
            
            for(String person : toVisit) {
                
                if(liveTogether(roommate, person)) {
                    
                    toRemove.add(person);
                    roommates++;
                }
            } 
            
            // we already found roommates group for these people, do not search here any more
            for(String remove : toRemove) {
                toVisit.remove(remove); 
            }
            
            return roommates;
        }
```